# Add a variable in functions.php and call it in single.php

Tags: php, functions

I am new to PHP and am building a WordPress theme. I would like to add a variable in the functions.php and use it in single.php as an if statement. At present, my single.php has the following code -

```
<?php 
  $prevPost = get_previous_post();
  $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, 'keepreading-thumb');

  if ( $prevPost ) : ?>
    <?php previous_post_link('%link',"$prevthumbnail"); ?>
    <h3><?php previous_post_link('%link'); ?></h3>
    <p><?php echo excerpt(25); ?></p>
  <?php endif; 
?>
```

I would like to have the `$prevPost` and `$prevthumbnail` variables to be defined in functions.php and would like to use them in an "if statement" in single.php.

P.S - I am a newbie in coding and would appreciate it if you can give me an answer in detail. Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

either use global variable
in functions.php:

```
    global $prevPost;
    $prevPost = 10;
```

in single.php :

```
    global $prevPost;
    if($prevPost)
     .. . . . Your code continues. .
```

Second method: define a function in functions.php and call that in single.php
 in functions.php :

```
    function func_prevPost(){
     $prevPost = 10;
     return $prevPost;
    }
```

in single.php :

```
    if(func_prevPost()){
    // your code here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I couldn't get the first one to work but the second one worked just fine. I am now using `if(func_prevPost()){` and it works. But, I cannot get the thumbnail to show up.

My actual code is `$prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, 'keepreading-thumb');`. How can I add the `$prevPost` inside the above code. Also, how would I add it to the functions.php? Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do that! This is easiest way:

Add your variables to a php files (e.g. config.php) and include it whenever you want to use its variables.

```
include('config.php');
```

Another easy way is using $_GET or $_POST variables.

```
$_GET['my_var']='123';
```

You can also define a global variable in functions.php.

```
global $my_var;
$my_var='123';
```

and then add global $my_var; before using it in single.php.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this code will **only** be used in single.php. Honestly I will stick with that code in single.php. Don't move it to functions.php and create a global varaible.

Globals might be useful at times, but I would advice you against adding variables to the global scope, unless you are using it itside a class or unless it is a really really necessarry.  Globals in classes will only be accesible by that particular class.

Just a tip, if you ever add anything to the global scope, use names that no one will ever think of, never use names that will be easily replicated, as this might lead to a clash later on with plugins, even wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for having a common space/ file where i can put name of the website and email address and use that variable across different pages. I found a plugin on wordpress which does exactly the same.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-global-variables/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).